# Why validation is not worked

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am working on Spring MVC project. I use `thymeleaf` as view. While click on `Register` button my `name` field is null but not get validation error for `@NotBlank` name field.

Here down is my code:

**Entity**

```
public class User {
    ...
    ...

    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter the your name !!")
    private String name;

    // getter setter
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "userentity") User user, 
                 BindingResult bindingResult, Model mdl)
    {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            System.out.println(bindingResult);
            mdl.addAttribute("userentity", user);
            return "signup";
        }
        smartService.saveUser(user);
        return "signup";
    }
```

**Thymeleaf**

```
<form th:action="@{/user}" method="post" th:object="${userentity}">
    
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
        <label class="form-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" 
        id="name"
        class="form-control form-control-lg"
        name="name" />
        <div class="text-danger" th:each="e: ${#fields.errors('name')}" th:text=${e}>
          
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body w-100">Register</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Dependencies uses for validation**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you import `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency in the same time?

Comment: Yes but not worked

Comment: There is not mistake in validation code. Can you restart application after adding validation dependency?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I restart my application and that's worked... Much Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your validation annotations only work if either the controller or your the method in your controller is annotated with

```
@Validated
```

so you should either have

```
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "userentity") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model mdl) {
```

or

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class YourControllerName {

private final SmartService smartService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "userentity") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model mdl) {
```

for your example that should be working. Be careful however with child objects and Lists. These additional need the @Valid annotation. I would suggest reading up on validation annotations here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated

Answer (score -1):

In your thymeleaf you should add this line `required autofocus="autofocus"` in your name input tag. Like -

```
<input id="firstName" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"
                           required autofocus="autofocus" />
```

this should work. It is running fine in my project.

Comment: I want server side validation by spring framework but Your code worked as html side validation.